# Attendees change event office 365 outlook add-in

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, office365-apps

I want to capture the change in attendees list of an appointment item inside my office 365 outlook addin. Whenever there is an attendee added / removed, I want to run a function inside my addin.

[Here](https://findtime.microsoft.com)
is one add-in that does it simple and nice. But I'm not able to find how to capture the change.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? It's been over 2 years and I'm also struggling with the same problem.

Comment: i solved that by placing a refresh button inside addin so that user will click refresh when needed

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no events that you can hook into within an Appointment or Message object from the [Mailbox API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn705877.aspx) that can give you access to real-time changes. In fact, I believe this FindTime add-in is using features that currently aren't publicly available from either the Office Add-ins framework, the JavaScript API for Office or the Mailbox API.

Note though their task pane is activated via a [ribbon button/add-in command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt267546.aspx).  My guess is that FindTime is using the [Outlook Notifications REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/notify-rest-operations) to get updates as the meeting recipients are updated by the user.  However, that API is currently in preview mode and I don't think you can use this yet for a production solution. Hope this helps!

Comment: This comes up quickly when trying to find out how to subscribe to subject changes in a outlook item. Is there a way to register a callback for item changes?

Comment: The Notifications REST API - link in my answer

Comment: Is that the best way from a task pane? If that's the case I'd rather just setInterval I think.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no direct callbacks that capture property changes in an item within the context of a task pane, so Notifications is the only way to go (if it can even be used properly in your situation)